# generate dataframe with not present values

Tags: r

I need to append to existing dataframe in such a way that if `c1` dataframe's `c1.b` column have not present `a1` vector's values then that not present value needs to get generated.

Example:

```
#c1 dataframe and a1 vector

c1 <- data.frame(c1.a = c(1),c1.b = c("1a"),c1.c = c(3))

a1 <- c("1a","1b","1c")
```

the dataframe that need to get generated as below

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = 5, ncol = 3))
names(df) <- c("c1.a","c1.b","c1.c")
```

Here, old `c1` dataframe have only "1a" present from a1 vector and missing are 1b and 1c. so those needs to get generated as below.

Please help me write a code.

```
> c1
   c1.a c1.b c1.c
1     1   1a    3
2     0   1b    0
3     0   1b    0
4     0   1b    0
5     0   1b    0
6     0   1b    0
7     0   1c    0
8     0   1c    0
9     0   1c    0
10    0   1c    0
11    0   1c    0
```

Comment: c1 is the end, df is just put for how generated values need to be. So expeted output is c1 @akrun

Comment: yes akrun. c1 i created because initially it dont have all the a1's value so later(output expected) its getting appended to c1 with not present values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` to get the names in 'a1' that are not the 'c1.b' column of 'c1', then `rep`licate the 'df' and 'v1' based on the length of 'v1' and `rbind` with the original 'c1'

```
v1 <- setdiff(a1, c1$c1.b)
df1 <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), length(v1)),]
df1$c1.b <- rep(v1, each = nrow(df))
c1 <- rbind(c1, df1)
row.names(c1) <- NULL
c1
#   c1.a c1.b c1.c
#1     1   1a    3
#2     0   1b    0
#3     0   1b    0
#4     0   1b    0
#5     0   1b    0
#6     0   1b    0
#7     0   1c    0
#8     0   1c    0
#9     0   1c    0
#10    0   1c    0
#11    0   1c    0
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
      mutate(c1.b = list(setdiff(a1, c1$c1.b))) %>% 
      unnest(c(c1.b)) %>%
      bind_rows(c1, .)
```